# Issue in edit and update function

Tags: php, laravel

`$request` does not have the WebsiteID and $validatedData also having WebsiteID as "NULL".
Below the code from `WebsiteController.php`

```
public function update(Request $request, Website $website)
{
    try {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'WebsiteName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'WebsiteURL' => 'required|url|max:255',
            'WebsiteUsername' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'WebsitePassword' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);

        $validatedData['WebsiteID'] = $website->getKey();
        $website->update($validatedData);

        return redirect()->route('websites.index')->with('success', 'Website updated successfully!');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['error'=>'An error occured while updating the website.']);
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple methods suggested by chatgpt but nothing worked.
I am expecting WebsiteID should have primary key value of the editing/updating record.

Comment: It does not look like you have enough context to assist you. Please share the full controller.

Comment: If the `$website` info being passed to the function is not in the `$request`, then that is the issue. Those will be null checking the request, and a some custom validation is necessary on the other Website-related values.